# Kusto query using TimeGenerated as Parameter

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I'm trying to use a Kusto query, taking the TimeGenerated field as input and get the below error.

Error is Query could not be parsed at 'datetime(start_time)'

```
let start_time =  Heartbeat | summarize min(TimeGenerated);
let end_time =  Heartbeat | summarize max(TimeGenerated);
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > datetime(start_time) and TimeGenerated < datetime(end_time)
```

It works, when I set a constant to start_time or even use ago() function.

Comment: P.S. `askql` has nothing to do with `kql`. see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/askql/info

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
let times = toscalar(
    T1
    | summarize pack_array(min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) 
)
;
T2
| where timestamp > todatetime(times[0])
| where timestamp < todatetime(times[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the toscalar() function doesn't seem to work. There a EOF error coming. Query could not be parsed at ';'

Comment: There was a missing `)` in the original answer. Try the query in the updated one.